# Why constructor not change server status and background color in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a little problem with my constructor. Imo I don't have any mistakes, so it should work fine, but something not works.

I have 2 Angular files - server.component.html and server.component.ts

**server.component.html**

```
<p [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: getColor()}">{{ 'Server' }} with ID {{ serverId }} is {{ getServerStatus() }}</p>
```

**server.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-server',
    templateUrl: './server.component.html'
})
export class ServerComponent {
    serverId: number = 10;
    serverStatus: string = 'offline';

    conctructor() {
        this.serverStatus = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'online' : 'offline';
    }

    getServerStatus() {
        return this.serverStatus;
    }

    getColor() {
      return this.serverStatus === 'online' ? 'green' : 'red';  
    }
}
```

So constructor should change my status and color. They don't do it, I have only red because I have only offline status. What's going on? I do the course, and I have the same code what my mentor.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZEcN.png)

Comment: console.log(this.serverStatus ) in your constructor to see what output you get in the console on your browser.

Answer (score 0):

css property is background-color not backgroundColor. Also, you missed single quotes(') around the background-color text in HTML. Update your html to this:

```
<p [ngStyle]="{'background-color': getColor()}">Server with ID {{ serverId }} is {{ getServerStatus() }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function on template could give you performace issue so I suggest to change it by template variables.

```
<p [ngStyle]="{'background-color': serverStatus === 'online' ? 'green' : 'red' }">{{ 'Server' }} with ID {{ serverId }}
    is {{ serverStatus }}</p>
```

And remove `getServerStatus()` and `getColor()` functions

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong here. It may cause of misspell your constructor name `constructor` instead of `conctructor`, Because of this `Angular` consider your method `conctructor` as method not a class lifecycle.

Please refresh this page based on value it change the color:

Reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dga6ds?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts